# svn: How to revert somebody else's commit?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, revert

Argh, somebody (OK, my boss) added and commited all the files in his directory, meaning all the svn files: conf/, db/, format, hooks/, locks/... I'm using Tortoise, so I tried clicking on each one and doing revert, it said OK, but I still see all of them under version control after update/commit.

We are now several versions past that. How do I clean things up ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Subversion, "revert" means to undo uncommitted changes to a working copy. What you're looking to do is to (effectively) undo a commit. This is normally done in Subversion with a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo)

Assuming that your boss did everything in a single commit (revision REVNUM), you'll just do the following in your working copy:

```
svn merge -c -REVNUM URL_TO_REPOSITORY_LOCATION
```

Then commit the new revision. All changes made in REVNUM will no longer be visible in the `HEAD` revision, and your revision history will show the changes committed, then merged back out.

Use the TortoiseSVN Merge context menu item to step through the same process.

Comment: Thanks, I'll know that for next time. Since I have access to the server, I did a dump/restore instead. I had to do a new checkout then but that's OK.

Comment: A dump/load is one of the most disruptive things you can do to your repository and users, and anything but the right way to do what you had to do. Look at it like open heart surgery - you don't get into it unless you **have** to.

Comment: For a repo with a very small audience (one developer and his boss, right?), this can be ok, though; especially when confidential documents have been committed which must not at all appear in it. However, the repo ID should normally be restored to the old value (before resuming usage; not in this case anymore), especially when many working copies exist.